# Algebraic uncertainty principle and the particle on a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm reading about the uncertainty principle formulated in the language of $ C^*$ algebras. It states that for any state $\omega: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a $C^*$ algebra and for any self-adjoint $a, b \in A$, we have
$$
\sigma_{\omega}(a)^{2} \sigma_{\omega}(b)^{2} \geq \frac{1}{4} \omega(i[a, b])^{2}
$$
So, what about the particle on a ring (one can read about it on wiki)? LHS vanishes here. In contrast to this formulation, in usual QM we have condition for domains of operators. Should this principle be reformulated because of this case?

Comment: phase operatpr(it is position op but on circle its just phase bounded in finite interval and periodic) is messy, so instead build your alebra from exponential of phase ops

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/338057/36194

Comment: thanks for helpful comments!

Comment: There is a beautiful paper by Levy-Lebond on this: [Who is afraid of nonhermitian operators?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491676902839) It's one of my favourites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this since I feel the linked question is essentially a duplicate: [Why doesn't the uncertainty principle contradict the existence of definite-angular momentum states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/why-doesnt-the-uncertainty-principle-contradict-the-existence-of-definite-angul)