# Coherent states and free motion on the circle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states

Consider the following formal implications:

> A quantum particle moving on the circle performs periodic motion even
> in the absence of an external potential. It can therefore be
> considered as a simple harmonic oscillator. It should then in
> principle be possible to define an annihilation operator, even though
> [it is well-known that operators on the circle are troublesome](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292633/why-doesnt-the-phase-operator-exist).
> One can then obtain coherent states on the circle as eigenstates
> of an annihilation operator associated to a free particle, in significant contrast to quantum mechanics on the line.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

**Edit:** For inspiration, here is the motion of an initial wavefunction $\psi \in \mathcal{L}_2(S^1)$. I think it can be solved analytically, but I did it numerically. What is left is to construct the annhilation operator.

[image]

Comment: "A quantum particle moving on the circle performs periodic motion even in the absence of an external potential" -- says who?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Isn't this a direct implication of periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: Not really (or at least, not directly). Wavepacket spreading is rather unlikely to be undone by simple propagation in the absence of a quadratic potential.

Comment: (That said, the energy eigenstates do have commesurate energy differences, so it's not implausible, but it needs to be argued in detail.)