# How to properly understand the commutator between angular momentum and angular coordinate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

When we study a single particle moving on a ring, we introduce the angular momentum $L$ and the angular coordinate $\phi$, which satisfy the following commutation relation
$$
[L,\phi]=-i\hbar.
$$
However, we also say $\phi$ itself is not a well-defined operator because $\phi$ and $\phi + 2\pi$ should be identified. One way to see this illness of $\phi$ is to consider the following expectation value of the above commutator
$$
\langle n|[L,\phi]| n \rangle = -i\hbar = 0
$$
where $|n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the angular momentum $L$.

My question is how we properly understand and use the commutation relation?   (Similar things appear the study of other models involving compact variables as well)

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292633/). You meant to write $L_z\sim -i\partial_\phi$.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338044/2451