Classical Hamilton’s equations in quantum mechanics
How can one derive what the position operator is in momentum space for a quantum wave function from the classical Hamilton’s equations?
Similarly, is a concept of an “angular momentum space” meaningful in quantum mechanics? Would their exist an “angle operator” in such a space?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292633/2451 and links therein.

Comments to the post (v2): 1. QM implies CM; not the other way around. 2. Consider to only ask 1 question per post.
